# Unit testing chained promises

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, sinon

How would I unit test a class method that calls an imported class's method that is a promise? I have the following structure:

```
import { SomeClass } from 'some-library';

class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
  myMethod() {
    const someClass = new SomeClass();

    return someClass.somePromiseMethod('someParam')
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(response => {
        // Do stuff
      });
  }
}
```

I have the following test

```
describe('myMethod', () => {
  it('does something', async () => {
    const inst = new MyClass();
    const stub = sinon.stub(SomeClass, 'somePromiseMethod')
      .resolves(Promise.resolve({
        data: [],
      }));

    await inst.myMethod();

    expect(stub.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Which is still pretty bare as I'm not sure how to approach this. Would it be better to break down the code in the `then`s?

**UPDATE**

Apparently `SomeClass` is a singleton and sinon was throwing an error saying `somePromiseMethod` is a `non-existent own property`. I changed the stub to call on its `prototype` instead and now the stub is being called.

```
class MyClass extends AnotherClass {
  myMethod() {
    const someClassInstance = SomeClass.getInstance();

    return someClassInstance.somePromiseMethod('someParam')
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(response => {
        // Do stuff
      });
  }
}


describe('myMethod', () => {
  it('does something', async () => {
    const inst = new MyClass();
    const stub = sinon.stub(SomeClass.prototype, 'somePromiseMethod')
      .resolves(Promise.resolve({
        data: [],
      }));

    await inst.myMethod();

    expect(stub.callCount).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Now, since then second `then` would just return `data`, I could just put `//Do stuff` in a separate function and test that.

Comment: You just need to test the public API of the class which is `myMethod`.  It seems like this test does that.  What exactly do you need to test?  If you need to wait for `myMethod` to finish, have it propagate the asynchronous chain by returning the Promise.  This is good practice anyway as you now have a way to know when `myMethod` completes.

Comment: The `await` in the test isn't going to do anything special because `myMethod` doesn't return a `Promise` right now.

Comment: Sorry, about that, forgot the `return`. Anyway, the `callCount` is still 0. As for testing `// Do stuff`, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Simply extract the logic in `// Do stuff` into a separate function and test it. Test separately `somePromiseMethod`. I'm not sure how much value there is in testing `response => response.data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stubbing out the wrong method `somePromiseMethod` exists on the `prototype` of `SomeClass` so you need to stub that instead. Sinon should let you do something like:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(SomeClass.prototype, 'somePromiseMethod')
  // You may be able to remove the Promise.resolve as well, as I think resolves does this for you
  .resolves({
    data: [],
  });
```

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the snippet. It still is 0. I also need to do testing in `// Do stuff`.

Comment: No problem, I've updated my answer for the updated question

Comment: This was it! Figured it out before your update but thank you!